# Error when using $ git push heroku master even though runtime.txt is correct

Tags: python, git, heroku, python-3.6, heroku-cli

I am trying to use $ git push heroku master but I get this error:

```
$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 6, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 534 bytes | 534.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote:  !     The latest version of Python 3 is python-3.6.5 (you are using , which is unsupported).
remote:  !     We recommend upgrading by specifying the latest version (python-3.6.5).
remote:        Learn More: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
remote: -----> Installing
remote:  !     Requested runtime () is not available for this stack (heroku-16).
remote:  !     Aborting.  More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to securibot.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/securibot.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/securibot.git'
```

My runtime.txt file reads the following:

```
python-3.6.5
```

Any idea why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the referenced URL that was posted?

If you look through https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes, you will see that "Newly created Python applications default to the Python 3.6.4 runtime".

You can specify your own run time in either your Pipfile or creating a runtime.txt with the following:

```
python-3.6.5
```

Comment: The OP mentioned `runtime.txt` with `python-3.6.5` in it.